# DXA import issue in Web 8.5

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-1.7

I am trying to install DXA 1.7 on Web 8.5 and am running into the below issue. Everything is over HTTP and not HTTPS. SDL, Web UI and WebServices all has Windows Authentication as "Enabled" in IIS. Tried passing CmsUser and password as parameters to the cmsimport command but no luck. Any idea what else is missing?

Command used is - .\cms-import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl "http:///"

Copied 'C:\Softwares\SDL DXA .NET 1.7\cms\DXA Application Data Definition.xml' to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\config\ImportExport\ApplicationData'
Get-CoreServiceClient : Exception calling "GetCurrentUser" with "0" argument(s): "The HTTP request is unauthorized
with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was
'Negotiate,NTLM'."
At C:\Softwares\SDL DXA .NET 1.7\cms\cms-import.ps1:138 char:22
+ $coreServiceClient = Get-CoreServiceClient "Service"
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-CoreServiceClient], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MessageSecurityException,Get-CoreServiceClient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying many options, I did unblock (in properties) each and every file in "cms" and "importexport" folders under the DXA 1.7 installable, was able to run the cms-import.ps1 without issues.

Comment: Did you note step 4 in the installation instructions? http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-D8644AF8-6EF4-47EB-91B3-04707B766C96

Comment: Ya, I did it only for the ps1 file but when I unblocked it for all files, I was able to import successfully.

Comment: It's a lot easier to do it on the zip file, indeed. Or use my script, it does that for you :) https://github.com/NunoLinhares/Web-8.5-Quick-Install/blob/master/Web-8.5-Quick-Install.ps1#L401

Comment: Yep. realized it. Thanks for the info Nuno and Bart.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same issue with DXA 2.2 import into  SDL Sites 9. But unblocking files didn't help
[image]

Comment: Resolved by entering cmsUserName and cmsUserPassword in powershell during call of cmsimport file. It is case sensitive, even though it is the same user in Tridion and Window, so windows takes user name all lower case for user name (domain/user name) so for execution of script, it is necessary to pass full user name  and password