# Connection error to Core Service

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion, https, iis7

We have SDL Sites 9.
We also implemented HTTPS for CM using OOTB script "SetupHTTPS.ps1".

The problem is that we are able to login to CME over HTTPS from any other machine in the network except the CM itself.

And when I'm trying to use powershell scripts that are trying to connect to Core Service I get an error.

The exact task is to import DXA sample site publications.

Example of powershell code:

```
cd d:\install\DXA\dxa\cms
.\cms-import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl "https://cm-int1.somehost.com/" -cmsUserName sdladmin -cmsUserPassword secure_pass
```

The result in powershell console:

```
"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'."
```

Any ideas howto fix it?

Now it looks for me as some configuration is needed on IIS side.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading DXA resources, was the Zip file 'unblocked' as noted in Step 4 of the documentation? https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v11/GUID-D8644AF8-6EF4-47EB-91B3-04707B766C96

(Look's very similar to [DXA import issue in Web 8.5](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/dxa-import-issue-in-web-8-5))

Comment: it was unblocked, I've just tried once again to unblock and import publications - same thing.

the problem is in authentication I believe. I'm not able to login to SDL CME over HTTPS also using https://DNS_NAME. But I'm able to login from any other instance in the same network over the same address without any issues.

Comment: This? https://webconnection.west-wind.com/docs/_4gi0ql5jb.htm

Comment: it worked for me! it is exactly what I was looking for!

@NunoLinhares your comment is the key to solve the problem with authentication! Many thanks!

Comment: @NunoLinhares Your Comment should be promoted to an Answer.

Comment: @RickPannekoek am I able to do it? If yes I don't know how :(

Comment: You can't, Nuno needs to add a new answer. Once he does, you may accept it so the question becomes closed.